Fabric js copied objects are removed after zooming or rotating in the canvas
I have a problem with copying and pasting objects in the canvas. The copy and paste functionalities itself work as expected, however, if I try to zoom in/out or rotate the canvas right after pasting the copied objects, the copied objects disappear from the canvas.
I have this code structure:
clipboard: fabric.Object;
@HostListener('window:keydown.control.c', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('window:keydown.meta.c', ['$event'])
  copy(): void {
    if (this.drawService.canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      this.drawService.canvas.getActiveObject().clone((cloned: fabric.Object) => {
        this.clipboard = cloned;
      });
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:keydown.control.v', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('window:keydown.meta.v', ['$event'])
  paste(): void {
    if (this.clipboard) {
      this.clipboard.clone((clonedObj: fabric.Object) => {
        this.drawService.canvas.discardActiveObject();
        clonedObj.set({
          left: clonedObj.left + 10,
          top: clonedObj.top + 10,
          evented: true,
        });
        if (clonedObj.type === 'activeSelection') {
          const activeSelection = clonedObj as fabric.ActiveSelection;
          activeSelection.canvas = this.drawService.canvas;
          activeSelection.forEachObject((obj: fabric.Object) => {
            this.drawService.canvas.add(obj);
          });
          clonedObj.setCoords();
        } else {
          this.drawService.canvas.add(clonedObj);
        }
        this.clipboard.top += 10;
        this.clipboard.left += 10;
        this.drawService.canvas.setActiveObject(clonedObj);
        this.drawService.canvas.renderAll();
      });
    }
  }

The objects are copied and pasted correctly at the right position. But whenever, right after pasting the object I click on zoom in/out buttons, or rotation button, any object/s, that were previously copied are gone.
However, if I add the the method for saving the canvas state at the end of the paste function:
saveCanvasState(): void {
  this.internalCanvasState = this.drawService.canvas.toJSON(); // Capture the current canvas state
  console.log('Current Canvas State:', this.internalCanvasState); // Log for debugging
}

I can see all the objects - original and copied, even if I don´t see copied ones on the canvas.
Can you suggest me some working solution where the copied objects stay on the canvas even if I zoom in/out, rotate the canvas?

Try clonedObject.setCoords() after copying

I already have clonedObj.setCoords(); implemented above.

@VictoriaErdődy as I can see you call .setCoords() an ActiveSelection. Try to call it on the actual objects that you add on the canvas by this.drawService.canvas.add;

@Vladim, I modified the method: if (clonedObj.type === 'activeSelection') {           const activeSelection = clonedObj as fabric.ActiveSelection;           activeSelection.canvas = this.drawService.canvas;           activeSelection.forEachObject((obj: fabric.Object) => {             this.drawService.canvas.add(obj);             obj.setCoords();           });         } else {           this.drawService.canvas.add(clonedObj);           clonedObj.setCoords();         } ,but it did not help. I still lose the copied objects once I refresh the page.

One thing I observed is that  else block - paste of individual object works fine and it keeps the position even after zoom in/out etc on canvas. The problem occurs only for activeSelection block, where the objects are positioned correctly at first, but after clicking on zoom in/out, they change the position and are shifted upwards and appear half hidden half shown on the top of the canvas.

I remember it was a bit tricky to deal with ActiveSelection and pasting. Try to remove an object from the ActiveSelection before inserting it to the canvas (activeSelection.remove() or canvas.add(...activeSelection.removeAll())

If I remove the object from the ActiveSelection, the position of the pasted objects is broken and appear somewhere on the top of the canvas, not below and to the right as defined: left: clonedObj.left + 10, top: clonedObj.top + 10,
